# Converting Pascal's "shr" to C's ">>"

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, pascal, bit-shift, shift

I'm having a problem translating some Pascal code into C.  Basically, I have nested loops, where the loop incrementing 'k' is within the loop incrementing 'i'.  In both cases, I want to execute the command "if i (right shifted by) k AND 1 = 1, then do the following {code}".  In Pascal I have:

```
{Pascal Code}
...
for i:=0 to N-1 do begin j:=0; temp:=N/2;
for k:=0 to P-1 do begin if ((i shr k) and 1)=1 then...
```

Which I know works.  I've plotted the data from the Pascal code and it is correct, so I assume this algorithm is what I want to replicate in C.  In C I have:

```
/*C code*/
...
int i;
unsigned int k;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   j=0;
   temp=N/2;
   for(k=0;k<P;k++){
      if((unsigned int)i)>>k&&1==1){
          /*do code*/
      }
```

In debugging these lines, I am writing to files that show what the values for Pascal's "i shr k" and C's "i>>k" are.  The first several lines of these files for each are:

```
Pascal's "i shr k":
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1...
```

My C results for "i>>k" are:

```
C's "i>>k":
1
2
1
3
1
4
2
1
5
2...
```

I've also found that in the Pascal version, there are many more visits to the inside of the "if" statement for a given value for i.  Any idea on what's going on here?  I know that Pascal's "shr" is a logical shift and that C's ">>" is an arithmetic shift, but I thought that putting (unsigned int) typecast in front of the left operand of ">>" would fix that?  Anybody have any advice on how to make my C statement equivalent to the Pascal statement?  It would be very much appreciated !

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why are you doing a typecast from int i to unsigned int i when you can just cast i to uint in the first place?

Comment: Hint: `&&` is a *logical* `and` operation. `&` is a *bitwise* `and`.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but since Pascal's "and" is a logical operator then wouldn't I want to use "&&" in C?  And I know it's silly to typecast i like that so i'm just gonna go ahead and change that now...thanks :)

Comment: you're missing the point that `and` in Pascal are both logical and bitwise operators

Comment: I'm not seeing the same prints in my i>>k test, I'm not sure how you generated 1,2,1,3... from i>>k.

Comment: `and` between booleans is logical and between integers is bitwise

Comment: whenever I enter the loop, I do "fprintf(fp_kshrcount,"%d\n",i>>k);", which is what's giving me those 1,2,1,3... values in my text file

Comment: [this documentaton](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/and.html#and) describes how `and` is bitwise for int-int, and logical for bool-bool. (On a 1-bit value, logical-AND and bitwise-AND have identical results, hwoever the logical one has short circuit evaluation).  It doesn't say what happens if you try to `and` an int with a bool though!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem appears to be with operator precedance.

In the Pascal version, your condition is this:

```
((i shr k) and 1)=1
```

In the C version, your condition is this (with some brackets added to show precedance):

```
(i >> k) && (1==1)
```

Also, `&&` is a logical operator, not a bitwise operator.  The equivalent bitwise operator is `&`.  If you add some brackets and switch operators, you should get what you want:

```
((i >> k ) & 1) == 1
```

Comment: +1 for the difference in [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Of course, the `== 1` isn't really necessary either.

Comment: No, but it's pretty common, because a lot of people prefer explicit rather than implicit conversions to boolean on stylistic grounds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Makes sense.  Code still isn't working though, is there a way to confirm that this code is giving me the results I want when compared to my Pascal code?  Using the same criterion above, when I evaluate "i>>k" in the loop, I get "1
1
3
1
1
5
1
3
1
7"

Comment: I don't know what inputs you're using for the Pascal and C code but the condition `(i >> k ) & 1` above should return the correct result

Comment: whenever I enter the loop, I do "fprintf(fp_kshrcount,"%d\n",i>>k);", which is what's giving me those 1,2,1,3... values in my text file

Comment: of course if you don't `and` to mask out the bits, it'll print all the bits. If Pascal is printing differently then that's because you provided it a different input, or your printing code is wrong

Comment: I see, maybe my printing code isn't a good litmus test for the equivalence of my functions.  But I still don't understand why "if(((i>>k) & 1) == 1)" in C would only enter the loop 2304 times while the Pascal code "if((i shr k and 1) = 1" enters that loop 4602 times...maybe the rough factor of 2 is a hint??

Comment: How much is `P`? if you shifted over the width of i then the result is undefined http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed.aspx Another possible reason maybe difference in sizes of types, if the Pascal code comes from ancient DOS then integer is 2 bytes while it's 4 bytes in most modern PC OSes. Because I don't know anything more about your code, I can't make more assumptions

Comment: P is 9.  I see what you are saying.  Maybe there is a way to scale that if statement then...

Comment: @user3763839 post a MVCE that shows the alleged erroneous number of loop entries in C